# Smarty iteration

Tags: php, smarty

Всем привет.

Столкнулся с проблемкой. Возможно, неправильно делаю... Суть вот в чем. Есть менюшка и в ней **8** пунктов меню!

```
<ul>
{foreach $arr AS $a}
<li>{$a.name}</li>
{if $a@iteration % 4 == 0}</ul><ul>{/if}
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Проблема в том, что в итоге получаю 3 ul. Т.е. получается так, что когда количество циклов достигает 4, то закрывается предыдущий ul и открывается следующий... Ну и в итоге генерирует 3 ul, что, в принципе, и логично, исходя из кода. Вопрос в том, как убрать последний пустой ul ? Точнее да же как правильно разбивать, чтобы не было такого косяка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто:

```
<ul>
{foreach $arr AS $a}
    <li>{$a.name}</li>
    {if $a@iteration % 4 == 0 && $a@iteration!=$arr|count}</ul><ul>{/if}
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Comment: Вот спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

что? А зачем так много UL?

```
<ul>
{foreach $arr AS $a}
<li>{$a.name}</li>
{if $a@iteration % 4 == 0}</ul>{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Ну и посмотрите результат вашего кода.
Добавляется </ul> в конце пустой.
Т.е. когда количество итераций достигает 4, то добавляет </ul>.
В данном случае 8 пунктов. Итераций в общем то же 8.

Выходом будет
<ul>
{foreach $arr AS $a}
<li>{$a.name}</li>
{if $a@iteration == 4}</ul><ul>{/if}
{/foreach}
</ul>
тогда будет только одно разделение. Ну это с учетом того, что пунктов всегда будет 8.